# How to interpret a 4 dimensional contigiency table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to understand this contingency table and I have no luck looking in the documentation of pandas or any other related questions. This is for a personal machine learning project.

I have the following example data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"la":[0,1,1,0,1], "lp1": [1,0,1,0,0], "lp2":[1,1,0,0,1], "lp3":[0,0,1,1,1], "lp4":[0,1,1,0,0]})
```

Hence we will have a Boolean contingency table. If I run:

```py
df.crosstab(index=df['la'], columns=[df['lp1'],df['lp2']])
```

I get the output:

```py
lp1  0     1   
lp2  0  1  0  1
la             
0    1  0  0  1
1    0  2  1  0
```

This can be better visualised in a table like so:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **lp1**: | **0** | **0** | **1** | **1** |
|  | **lp2**: | **0** | **1** | **0** | **1** |
| **la** | **0** | *1* | *0* | *0* | *1* |
|  | **1** | *0* | *2* | *1* | *0* |

Which can be better understood as (e.g.) there were `2` occurrences of `lp1=0 lp2=1 and la=0` in the dataset. However, if I run:

```py
pd.crosstab(index=df['la'], columns=[df['lp1'],df['lp2'],df['lp3']])
```

I expect a table like this:

```py
lp1  0           1   
lp2  0     1     0     1
lp3  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1 
la                
0    1   #results here
1    0
```

Instead, I get:

```py
lp1  0        1   
lp2  0  1     0  1
lp3  1  0  1  1  0
la                
0    1  0  0  0  1
1    0  1  1  1  0
```

I have no idea how to interpret this table. I am unsure why there is a repeating label (the repeating 1 in lp3), why the labels suddenly change order from `0,1` to `1,0`. This continues for higher dimensions (e.g. 5 dimensions):

```py
pd.crosstab(index=df['la'], columns=[df['lp1'],df['lp2'],df['lp3'],df['lp4']])
```

produces:

```py
lp1  0        1   
lp2  0  1     0  1
lp3  1  0  1  1  0
lp4  0  1  0  1  0
la                
0    1  0  0  0  1
1    0  1  1  1  0
```

It all makes sense to me until you have a table > 3 dimensions. I am running Python 3.10 and pandas 1.3.4.

I have tried to go through the source code, docs and related StackOverflow questions and I have not found an answer.

How do I properly interpret this 4 dimensional table, please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, basically, the columns whose elements are all NaN are dropped so truncate the output due to `dropna`, which is set to `True` by default:

> **dropna**: ***bool***, ***default*** ***True***
>
> Do not include columns whose entries are all NaN. This means that the table I showed above simply does not contain these columns.

Hence, setting `dropna` to `False` made the table more readable (to me). So if I run:

`pd.crosstab(index=df['la'], columns=[df['lp1'],df['lp2'],df['lp3']], dropna=False)`

I get output:

```
lp1  0           1         
lp2  0     1     0     1   
lp3  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
la                         
0    0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
1    0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0
```

which is much more clear.

In conclusion: rtfm